# Stacking menu items under eachother

Tags: html, css, sass

I got a menu with submenus, but they dont stack. They are all pushed into one tiny space.
What did I do wrong?

I am using scss btw so I hope it makes sense ill post my css output also.

Thanks in advance!

My css code:

```
#nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    left: -1000px;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}

#menu {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: $myriad;
  color: $white;
  background-color: $lightpurple;
  border: 1px solid $lightpurple;
  ul {
    margin-left: -40px;
    display:block;
  }
  li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 15px;
    &:hover {
      background-color: $darkpurple;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  }
 a {    
    color: $white;
    text-decoration:none;
    &:hover{
    color: $lightgray; 
    }
        i {
            font-size:9px;
            &.icon{
                font-size:17px;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My html code:

```
 <nav id="menu">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href =#><i class="fa fa-home icon"></i></a></li>
            <li>
            <a href =#>Leden <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul><li><a href=#>Info lidmaatschap</a></li></ul>
            <ul><li><a href=#>Ledenoverzicht</a></li></ul>
            <ul><li><a href=#>Ledenkaart</a></li></ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href =#>Stromingen <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href =#>Publicatie's <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href =#>Activiteiten <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href =#>Werkgroepen <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href =#>Nieuws <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href =#>Webshop <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href =#><i class="fa fa-search icon"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
```

my css output:

```
* line 9, ../sass/_header.scss */
#menu {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "myriad pro";
  color: white;
  background-color: #7a76b4;
  border: 1px solid #7a76b4;
}
/* line 15, ../sass/_header.scss */
#menu ul {
  margin-left: -40px;
}
/* line 18, ../sass/_header.scss */
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
}
/* line 21, ../sass/_header.scss */
#menu li:hover {
  background-color: #5b5896;
  padding: 15px;
}
/* line 26, ../sass/_header.scss */
#menu a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* line 29, ../sass/_header.scss */
#menu a:hover {
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
/* line 32, ../sass/_header.scss */
#menu a i {
  font-size: 9px;
}
/* line 34, ../sass/_header.scss */
#menu a i.icon {
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "Display: inline;" tag from the "li" tag and it will do the job i think!

Comment: This is the jsfiddle, I removed the submenus now to make it more easy to see. Do you know what to do? http://jsfiddle.net/aLhPr/

Answer (score 0):

This following code may works correctly, as you need

> - jsFiddle demo
>
> ```
>     #menu
>     {   
>         height:80px;
>         font-size: 15px;
>         font-family: "myriad pro";
>         color: white;
>         background-color: #7a76b4;
>         border: 1px solid #7a76b4;
>     }
>     /* line 15, ../sass/_header.scss */
>     #menu ul
>     {
>         margin-left: -40px;
>     }
>     /* line 18, ../sass/_header.scss */
>     #menu li
>     {
>         display: inline-block;
>         padding: 15px;
>         vertical-align:top;
>     }
>     /* line 21, ../sass/_header.scss */
>     #menu li:hover
>     {
>         background-color: #5b5896;
>         padding: 15px;
>     }
>     /* line 26, ../sass/_header.scss */
>     #menu a
>     {
>         color: white;
>         text-decoration: none;
>     }
>     /* line 29, ../sass/_header.scss */
>     #menu a:hover
>     {
>         color: #9e9e9e;
>     }
>     /* line 32, ../sass/_header.scss */
>     #menu a i
>     {
>         font-size: 9px;
>     }
>     /* line 34, ../sass/_header.scss */
>     #menu a i.icon
>     {
>         font-size: 17px;
>     }
>
>     #smenu ul
>     {
>         display: none;
>     }
>
>     #smenu:hover #li1
>     {
>         display: block;}
>     }
> </style> </head> <body>
> <nav id="menu">
>     <ul id="nav">
>         <li id"mmenu"><a href =#><i class="fa fa-home icon"></i></a></li>
>         <li id="smenu">
>         <a id="showmenu" href =#>Leden <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
>         <ul id="li1"><li><a href=#>Info lidmaatschap</a></li></ul>
>         <ul id="li1"><li><a href=#>Ledenoverzicht</a></li></ul>
>         <ul id="li1"><li><a href=#>Ledenkaart</a></li></ul>
>         </li>
>         <li><a href =#>Stromingen <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
>         <li><a href =#>Publicatie's <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
>         <li><a href =#>Activiteiten <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
>         <li><a href =#>Werkgroepen <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
>         <li><a href =#>Nieuws <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
>         <li><a href =#>Webshop <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
>         <li><a href =#><i class="fa fa-search icon"></i></a></li>
>     </ul>
>     </nav> </body> </html>
> ```